# How to crop a image from the selected contour in opencv android

Tags: android, opencv

In my project i wanted to select a object from live camera feed and then create a **JPEG** file only of that selected region. So in **onCameraFrame** method i have set the parameter 0 in `Imgproc.drawContours(mRgba, contours, 0, CONTOUR_COLOR);` to select the first item which is the selected one. Then i have tried to implement a bound rectangle for that item.

## OnCameraFrame()

public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
        mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();

```
    if (mIsColorSelected) {
        mDetector.process(mRgba);
        List<MatOfPoint> contours = mDetector.getContours();
        Log.e(TAG, "Contours count: " + contours.size());
        Imgproc.drawContours(mRgba, contours, 0, CONTOUR_COLOR);

        Mat colorLabel = mRgba.submat(4, 68, 4, 68);
        colorLabel.setTo(mBlobColorRgba);



        MatOfPoint2f contour2f = new MatOfPoint2f( contours.get(0).toArray());
        //Processing on mMOP2f1 which is in type MatOfPoint2f
        double approxDistance = Imgproc.arcLength(contour2f, true)*0.02;
        Imgproc.approxPolyDP(contour2f, approxCurve, approxDistance, true);

        //Convert back to MatOfPoint
        MatOfPoint points = new MatOfPoint( approxCurve.toArray() );

        // Get bounding rect of contour
        Rect rect = Imgproc.boundingRect(points);
        Mat selectedRegion = mRgba.submat(rect);

        Bitmap bmp = null;
        try {

            bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(selectedRegion.cols(), selectedRegion.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            convertBitmapToImage(bmp);

        } catch (CvException e) {
            Log.d("Exception", e.getMessage());
        }


    }


    return mRgba;
}
```

And then converted the mat object to a bitmap and saved it as a **JPEG** format

## convertBitmapToImage

```
private void convertBitmapToImage(Bitmap bmp) {

        File root = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + "/Dummy");
        if (!root.exists()) {
            root.mkdirs();
        } else {
            System.out.print("Exists");
        }

        File f = new File(root, "filename.jpeg");
        //Convert bitmap to byte array
        Bitmap bitmap = bmp;
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 60, bos);
        byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();


        try {

            f.createNewFile();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        //write the bytes in file
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
            fos.write(bitmapdata);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

But it creating a blank **JPEG** file

[image]

What's i am doing wrong or what needs to be done

Comment: check once that image is saving in external storage and you are getting the path of that image

Comment: this is the saved image in the image path that i just posted!!

Answer (score -1):

I don't check your code, but I think that problem is with your bmp.
You should use sth like this:

```
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(src.cols(), src.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Utils.matToBitmap(src, bmp);
```

befor your convertBitmapToImage method.
src is your Mat object which you want save as image file.